# Declaring a List of types

Tags: c#, list, types

I want to declare a list containing types basically:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>() {Button, TextBox };
```

is this possible?

Comment: I am working on a set of functions to verify/validate data Users enter in a form.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>() { typeof(Button), typeof(TextBox) };
```

The `typeof()` operator is used to return the `System.Type` of a type.

For object instances you can call the `GetType()` method inherited from Object.

Comment: Change the declaration to use `var` and you have my up-vote. :P

Comment: A slight variation of the scenario for posterity: if you have an instance/object and want to include its type in the same list use the object's .GetType() property -- e.g. see 'myButton' variable usage in the following:

Button myBtn = new Button();
List<Type> types = new List<Type>() { myBtn.GetType(), typeof(TextBox) };

Comment: If this is declared somewhere else than in a method body type the var keyword isn't available. But yes you could (and should) use var in a method.

Comment: Change the decleration to use var, and you have my down-vote. :P

Answer (score 14):

You almost have it with your code. Use typeof and not just the name of the type.

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>() {typeof(Button), typeof(TextBox) };
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use `List<System.Type>`

```
var types = new List<System.Type>();
```

To add items to the list, use the typeof keyword.

```
types.Add(typeof(Button));
types.Add(typeof(CheckBox));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>{typeof(String), typeof(Int32) };
```

You need to use the typeof keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Use a typed generic list:

```
List<Type> lt = new List<Type>();
```