# dropdown list with all DataType in C#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

How I can do dropdownlist to contain all datatype in C#

System.Int32,System.string

So Ican select type Of varible from this DropDown

Comment: You mean a `ComboBox`?  Is this winforms or ASP.NET?

Comment: "System.Int32,System.string" these are not datatypes what do you mean? all types?

Comment: Do you mean a combobox that contains a list of types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for the list of primitive types, you can find one here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfa3fa08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Or, if you want a method returning a List of primitive types, try this:

```
public List<Type> GetTypes(){
        return typeof(int).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsPrimitive).ToList();
    }
```

Since it uses Linq, you will need:

`using System.Linq;`

Comment: I Know, put is there any method to get all this type ??

Comment: "the list of value types" This lists the fundamental types in .NET, not all the value types available.  In fact, this list doesn't even contain all the value types in the `System` namespace.  For instance, `DateTime` is a struct in the `System` namespace, but it's not on this list.

Comment: Fair point.  The assumption I made based on the question is that he was looking for primitive types.  I've updated my verbiage.

Comment: Very Good 
But I cant see in DropDownlist string and DataTime ??

Comment: As far as I know, to .Net, those are just an an arbitrary class and struct respectively.  You could remove the 'Where' clause if you want ALL types in the System namespace, but that will be 1000+ types.  What about Guid?  What about TimeSpan?  Since your requirements are arbitrary, you will need to maintain your own list.

Answer (score 2):

Finally,

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(System.TypeCode))
```

This what am talking about

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `List<Type>` as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615723/declaring-a-list-of-types). Use this list as the data for your `ComboBox`.

If you need to get all the types automatically, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315665/c-list-all-classes-in-assembly) answer

Comment: You'll need to make the labels use a value of type `String` so that they show, otherwise no items will appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through the assemblies and get all types' names.

```
private List<string> GetTypes()
{
    List<string> typeNames = new List<string>();

    /// or AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() or loop through the folder with assemblies
    Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    foreach (AssemblyName an in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies() )
    {
        foreach (Type type in an.GetTypes())
        {
            typeNames.add(type.Name);
        }  
    }
    return typeNames;
}
```

Of if you just want to list the basic types go to the C# spec and just edit the combobox.

Comment: don't believe "an.GetTypes()"  is right, more like  "an.GetType()" but this still is not going to have a definition for GetEnumerator