# Java ".class" property - C# equivalent

Tags: java, c#

I have read through both of the ".class" explanations ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072066/about-the-class-property-field),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076629/how-does-a-class-property-work)) but I'm struggling to understand what the ".class" property does.

I have just started Java but have been programming in C# for a while. Is there any similar function in C# to this .class property? It might help me understand what this is.

Comment: Might be wrong, but it is like typeof in C# in my view.

Comment: I'd say that `Type.class` is approximately the same as `typeof(Type)`

Comment: `MyClass.class` Java <-> `typeof(MyClass)` C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's typeof in C#, your 2nd link explains it better.

Comment: So does that mean that `List<Class<? extends A>> list = new ArrayList<Class<? extends A>>();` would be similar to a `List<Type>` in c#?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that that list was then used like this: `list.add(B.class)`?

Comment: I think here B is like class B {} : A

Comment: So if we are adding Types to a List then that would be a List<Type>?

Comment: Yes, see here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615723/declaring-a-list-of-types